# Firing hCaptcha callback function for bypass token

Tags: c#, selenium, callback, discord, captcha

I'm trying to bypass the **hCaptcha** in [Discord Account Registration](https://discord.com/register) using selenium webDriver in C#. I'm using [CapMonster Cloud](https://capmonster.cloud/) API for solving the captcha itself and as response I'm getting bypass token.

The problem that I currently have is that I can't locate the callback function that I need to call/submit, in order to pass the hCaptcha.

I'm setting the bypass token into "g-recaptcha-response" and "h-captcha-response" textareas, but can't find a way to locate and call the callback function. There is no form to be submitted.

Comment: What do the traffic logs look like. You can use a man in the middle proxy (like fiddler) to check the network logs and view the request that deals with captcha.

Comment: But that's the point, when solving the captcha it's not sending bypass token in the request. It sends the pictures ... So I use external API for solving that and I get back a token. But have no idea where to submit it ....

Comment: You have to inspect the vue properties of the component. I'm not going to post a solution here because I like discord, but there is a function there that does it.

Comment: Was your problem resolved? I gave you a generic answer on how to do it. If you still cant find it let me know.

Comment: Nope, still struggling. I'm not much of a frontend developer, so that's why I put up a bounty. I need the exact solution ...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @StefanTaseski

Comment: Exact solution is right here https://medium.com/@aleksandlario/how-to-automate-midjourney-image-generation-with-puppeteer-6aea1b366c75

Answer (score 0):

> using selenium webDriver in C#

10/10 Would recommend doing discord captcha bypasses using:

**PuppeteerExtraSharp/ExtraStealth**

*(as selenium has some obvious tracers)*

Puppeteer has a lot more freedom in it's API as well as the fact that [2capthca](https://2captcha.com/blog/solve-hcaptcha) is a much more popular method for solving h-captchas

I know this doesn't answer your question but i hope you look into this as a potential better alternative if you do not receive a more traditional answer.

Comment: I'll look into it. So this offers captcha solving as a functionality?

Comment: Yes! I'm much more familiar with it's javascript counterpart, but this will definitely achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm trying this solution right now, but I'm not sure if it works with hCaptcha. I see the implementation is for ReCaptcha ... any idea if this can be used for hCaptcha as well?

Comment: Managed to get to the point where it need to call the callback function, but it's not working as this is totally different captcha. This implementation is just for ReCaptcha, it's not handling the hCaptcha :(

Comment: That's strange, their site states that they solve both (as h-captcha is just a re-implementation of re-captcha). Do you mind sharing more about the process and what exactly is occurring? My theory is that their bot protection is triggering on your end, but as I have no information, I could be wrong.

Comment: The javascript function that they are using at the end doesn't work, it throws exceptions for hCaptcha.

Comment: Sorry if it doesn't end up working, but here are my last resources I can send you for it (regarding 2captcha): https://github.com/2captcha/2captcha-csharp || https://2captcha.com/p/hcaptcha

Comment: I got this far:
hcaptcha.execute("captcha-id", "bypass-token");

But it's still missing something ... not sure what. It's not recognizing it. I'm getting message "no bypass_token found".

Comment: you do have a token for 2-captcha services right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Anti-Captcha.com](https://anti-captcha.com/apidoc/articles/how-to-integrate-the-plugin) plugin which will do the job automatically. It injects its own callbacks, so when a token is ready it submits the form. If you ever have problems with plugin, support guys [here](https://antcpt.com/eng/support.html) will help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Web communication has to happen in one of the methods defined on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

So if anything is being sent and received from a server to the browser it has to be one among those methods. Generally the most common methods are `POST` and `GET`.

The statement "There is no form to be submitted" is somewhat confusing. A form is just display of fields to collect data from a user. In case a website does not need user input they do not show the form. They would instead capture the required data and send a POST request to the server (without the user ever noticing), in a manner similar to how a form would have sent the data. This is a normal behavior for almost all major websites. An example is google-analytics codes.

So what you need to look for is a `POST` request (mostly or `PUT` maybe `GET` - depends) where the data you are targeting is `received` or `sent`.

In your case there indeed is a form which displays the captcha (that is how you see it) and and associated `POST` request which does what you need.

```
Url for the post request on the captcha is POST /getcaptcha?s=xxxxxxxx-xxxe-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/3
 
Url where it is sent is POST /api/v9/auth/register HTTP/3
```

These basics apply to any web communication and not just the website in question.